# Getting the error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, prototype, appendchild

Am using pure javascript prototype functions to create a list of checkbox and append them as we iterate over the data. Everything is created using javascript and css. 
When I run it so it can draw a list of checkboxes, it throws me an error :

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."
```

for this line:

```
results.push(this.list.appendChild(letter.draw));
```

Am sure there is nothing wrong with checkboxinput prototype since it works fine everywhere else. There is something wrong am doing in FormTicket.Can anyone help me what am doing wrong?
The form page is FormTicket

```
FormTicket.prototype.respond = function(data) {
  var letter, i, len;
  this.letters = [];
  for (i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    letter = data[i];
    this.letters.push(new ParaInfo({
      InfoIndividual: letter
    }));
  }
  return this.drawList();
};

FormTicket.prototype.drawList = function() {
  var letter, i, len, ref, results;
  ref = this.letters;
  results = [];
  for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
    letter = ref[i];
    results.push(this.list.appendChild(letter.draw));
  }
  return results;
};
```

The draw function in the ParaInfo method is:

```
 ParaInfo.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.e = new CheckBoxInput({
    title: this.InfoIndividual,
    float: 'left',
  });
  return this.e;
};
```

and just FYI, the checkboxinput is another prototype, part of it as below:

```
CheckBoxInput.prototype.build = function(arg) {
  this.title = arg.title;
  this.float = arg.float;
};

CheckBoxInput.prototype.draw = function() {
  var box, check;
  this.item = document.createElement('div').addClass('checkboxInput');
  return this.item;
};
```

Comment: I haven't examined very closely, but it looks like you're trying to call append the function `letter.draw` to a DOM node. You can't append functions; you can only append DOM nodes. Did you mean to *call* `letter.draw` and append the return value of the call? Or do you expect `letter.draw` to be something other than a function inside of `drawList`?

Comment: @apsillers I mean to call letter.draw and append the return value of the call. So, when i call the drawList function, its return value basically draws the checkboxes one by one

Comment: `letter.draw` is a reference to the function object. `letter.draw()` is a call to the function and refers to its return value. You use the first form; it seems you want to use the second form instead.

Comment: @apsillers I figured that might be the issue so I tried using the .draw() but then it gives me the following error: Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined. So I got confused.

Comment: @apsillers solved it. needed to call ".draw().draw()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. needed to call ".draw().draw()"
i.e Initially was calling .draw() of ParaInfo only. Added another ".draw()" which calls the draw of CheckBoxInput. Correct call for append:

```
  results.push(this.list.appendChild(letter.draw().draw()));
```

Thanks to user apsillers for his valuable input as well.